# How to use React library on Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vue.js

I am having an issue to use React library on Vuejs.

I was trying to use Zendesk Garden (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zendeskgarden/react-loaders) on my Vuejs project.

Actually, I manage to show the loader using Vuera library (https://github.com/akxcv/vuera), but it only works if I use it without the typescript.

This the code that works for me (HelloWorld.vue):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ThemeProvider>
      <Spinner />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ThemeProvider } from '@zendeskgarden/react-theming';
import { Spinner } from '@zendeskgarden/react-loaders'

export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  components: { ThemeProvider, Spinner }
}

</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
</style>
```

However, if I use class-based component or typescript, the loader is not showing.

This the code that doesn't work for me (HelloWorld.vue):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ThemeProvider>
      <Spinner />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import { ThemeProvider } from '@zendeskgarden/react-theming';
import { Spinner } from '@zendeskgarden/react-loaders'

@Component({
  components: {
    ThemeProvider, Spinner
  }
})
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
</style>
```

This is main.ts:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
//@ts-ignore
import { VuePlugin } from 'vuera'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(VuePlugin)

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

and this is App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js + TypeScript App"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

@Component({
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
})
export default class App extends Vue {}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Do you have any idea why the loader doesn't work if I use class-based component or typescript?

Thanks a lot!

**Updated:**

This is an error when I tried to build:

[image: build-error]

Comment: it would be great if you show us any kind of error message

Comment: @Ifaruki, I have updated the question with error when build.

Comment: did you checked this out? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html

Comment: @avdnowhere I was thinking of trying out the same thing! Did you get this to work? This is Vue 2, right? I didn't see anything about anybody trying this in Vue 3, but it seems like trying Vue 2 is a better bet first.

Comment: FWIW, I tried setting up a vanilla Vue 2.x app with vue-cli and was able to add a button from React Zendesk Garden components. Cool that it works, but I'll probably just use Vuetify. I decided I don't really care if my app looks a little different. Vue 3 didn't work - at least not the way I tried it, but I expected that. I got a `Invalid hook call` error in the console from React.

Comment: Did you solve your problem with TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

In the main.ts. try `import VuePlugin from 'vuera'`